# Airpods stopped working, reset unhelpful

Tags: bluetooth, airpods

Few days ago my right airpod wouldn't work, I placed it in my ear and it didn't connect.
I decided to forget the device from the bluetooth list and try resetting it.
Afterwards, the whole device is not being detected at all under the Bluetooth (other Bluetooth device do work fine). This is happening also with another phone I tested so problem is not with the iPhone.

Another thing I noticed is that when I charge the airpods box, it seems to charge fine, but once I leave it out of charge even for a day, there is no light at all once I open the box which seems to mean battery has depleted even though I didn't use it.

I'm very disappointed, these are the second-generation airpods, and I have them for less than two years. Apple advised me to take them to a "lab".

What is it they will check at the lab, what could be broken, and isn't there a way I can try fixing it myself? it just happened out of the blue.

Comment: When long-pressing the button on the back does the LED start flashing white? If it flashes does it show up in Bluetooth preferences of any device (iPhone, Mac, ...)? (If the AirPods are already paired, remove them in Bluetooth settings first).

In the "lab" (I assume they mean an Authorised Service Provider) they have diagnostic software to check the AirPods and Case.

Comment: if the box was recently charged, yes it will flash white, but it does not show on neither my two iphone devices.